# Show that if the sum of an diverges, no discrete probability space can contain independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $0\leq p_n\leq 1$, and put $a_n= \min \{p_n, 1-p_n\}$. Show that if 
$\sum a_n$ diverges, then no discrete probability space can contain independent events $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ such that $A_n$ has probability $p_n$.

Comment: Welcome to SE ! Consider adding some further details about your problem and properly explain which part you get stuck on . Nobody here will do your homework for you, cheers !

Comment: Hi Victor, sorry about that. Here's where I am at the moment: I'm assuming that if for each i, $B_j$ is either $A_i$ or $A_i'$, then $B_1$ intersect ....$B_2$...intersect $B_n$ has the probability at most product of (1-$a_i$)$\leq$exp(-$\sum ai$).

Hope this helps.

Trust me I've been tackling this for like 2 hours lol

Comment: At first I thought: what if $p_n=1/2$ for every $n$, so that $\sum_n A_n = 1/2+1/2+1/2+\cdots=\infty$, and yet there is a space with independent events each with probability $1/2$.  Then I noticed it said "discrete".  So "discrete" is essential.  I would normally take it to mean that point masses account for all of the probability, $\text{i.e. }\displaystyle \sum_{\omega\in\Omega} P(\{\omega\})=1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's do not consider the $P_n=0$ cases, because if the empty set is independent with any sets.

So , consider the discrete probability space, contains at most countable many points with each point assigned with a positive probability.

All the probabilities sum up to 1.

Now $\sum a_n$ diverge,

suppose $A_n$ are the events,

they are independent, therefore $P(\bigcap_n A_n)=\prod_n a_n=0$, here because $p_n$ are at most $\frac{1}{2}$,

then $\bigcap_n A_n$ is simply empty in our discrete setting.

(*) indeed, if we choose any infinite $A_n$ their intersection will be empty.

Use Borel-Cantelli lemma, $\sum a_n$ diverge then $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n$ will have measure $1$, in our discrete setting this means $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n$ is the whole set.

This would imply that any point in our set will be contained in infinitely many $A_n's$

Contradict with (*)

The whole point is that in discrete probability space, measure 0 set is empty and measure 1 set is the whole set. (of course, the points with 0 probability we can simply delete them without changing anything).

Hope it will help. :D